# TinyMCE 4 Plugins: Can't get tinymce.Editor.getLang() working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am currently switching a plugin from TinyMCE 3.x to the new version TinyMCE 4.0.26. I encountered heavy problems when trying to internationalize my plugin labels.

Within my plugin.js, I am loading the language pack by calling

```
tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('myplugin');
```

with my i18n file *langs/de.js* looking something like this:

```
tinyMCE.addI18n('de', {
  myplugin: {
    button : 'Link einf\u00FCgen/bearbeiten',
    title : 'Link einf\u00FCgen/bearbeiten'
  }
});
```

When I access the the static context

```
tinymce.i18n.data.myplugin
```

I can see that both variables *button* and *title* are available.

THE PROBLEM:

When calling *editor.getLang('myplugin.button')* I get *{#myplugin.button}* instead of the appropriate variable value.

After I investigated the source code a little bit, I found out that it expects the language code to exist within the tinyMCE.i18n.data....., which is not available

```
getLang: function(name, defaultVal) {
            return (
                this.editorManager.i18n[(this.settings.language || 'en') + '.' + name] ||
                (defaultVal !== undefined ? defaultVal : '{#' + name + '}')
            );
        },
```

@see https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/4.0.26/js/tinymce/classes/Editor.js#L1105

Have I done something wrong? Has anyone created a plugin for the new TinyMCE version and managed to get the internationalization working?

Comment: at least you can see the variables available, on mine, the object data is empty :( any solution on this as of yet? i'm under the same issue. Using Tiny 4.1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, who tried to help me out on this. Unfortunately I could not make my plugin work with translated labels in the popup window, but finally found a solution.

Everything below works perfectly okay and easy in TinyMCE version 4.2.6.

Here the steps to make everything work with a plugin named *example*:

- Create your plugin directory at *plugins/example*
- Create the required plugin JS file *plugins/example/plugin.min.js* ( take a look at the example http://pastebin.com/jEARrtWN ) - As @msqar recommended I added the *requireLangPack* call right before my plugin function.
- Now create your translation files ( Please replace de_AT by your language code ) at *langs/de_AT.js* and *plugins/example/langs/de_AT.js*

```js
tinymce.addI18n('de_AT', {
  'Title': 'Titel',
  'Example plugin': 'Beispielplugin'
});
```

- All the ( in my example ) english labels are **automatically** translated to de_AT when setting up TinyMCE like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="test"></textarea>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('textarea').tinymce({
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: 'example',
            toolbar: 'example',
            language:'de_AT'
        });
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The result**

When opening the dialog using the button inside the toolbar, the window title *Example plugin* is automatically translated to *Beispielplugin*

**NO special calls** to editor.getLang required.

I hope this guide works for other developers around here too. I would appreciate any positive or negative feedback.

Thanks a lot to all the developers here at @stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to directly access the right strings:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.i18n.data[ed.getParam('language') + '.myplugin_name']['my_key'];
```

Comment: @msqar: what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work, maybe it can help, this is 1 year old though, but can help others. 
Since the entire way of creating a plugin changed from 3.X to 4.X, the requireLangPack i was adding to my plugin was in an incorrect location.

I was doing:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor, url) {
     tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('myplugin');
     ...
});
```

When it should be:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('myplugin');
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor, url) {

         ...
});
```

Also, the way I accessed those variables was:

```
editor.getLang("myplugin").title;
```

Instead of

```
editor.getLang("myplugin.title");
```

Hope it works for other people under the same circumstance.

Comment: Still not working for me, moreover even though my language is `zh_TW` it loads `langs/en.js`...
[The documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/#exampleofaswedishtranslationforthedialogtitle) lacks of example